# Redis "Fatal error, can't open config file 'restart'" after a crash

Tags: redis

So after restarting my httpd redis crashed (due to the number of sudden requests sent via httpd and written on redis) and now when I try to restart redis on my centos 6.5 server I get the following error:

[root@host /]# /usr/sbin/redis-server restart
[1705] 17 Apr 00:30:49 # Fatal error, can't open config file 'restart'

I have also tried to login to redis using `redis-cli` and I get an error stating the connection to the server failed.

What options do I have to safely restart the server?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing a similar issue on a test server. I'm symlinking my `/etc/redis.conf` file from `/root/redis.conf`. This works with every other daemon.

Answer (score -2):

From the /src directory where you downloaded and unzipped your redis source, run the following. This is for RHEL based systems.

```
make install
# (OR)
sudo cp src/redis-server /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```